# how can i convert my web site wordpress to an android app?

Tags: json, wordpress, android-studio

Is there a simple way to transform My web site which i create with wordpress to an android application ? I have not found a plugin that does
someone can hepl me Knowing that I am a beginner in android

Answer (score 0):

You can install jetpack plugin on wordpress to get your site api and then implement it in your application and make the design.

If you wish you can implement web view and just give your site url and make it but your site needs to be full responsive but that is not recommended cus its like opening a site in your browser and it's really slow.